# Unable to draw KDE on python

Tags: python

I've created a Brownian motion and then I have taken the last values of 1000 entries repeated 10000 times. I was able to plot the histogram using the following code as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
\\BM represents list of values generated by the Brownian motion
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
ax1.hist(BM[:,-1],12)
```

I've been able to draw the KDE as follows, however i unable to merge the two diagrams together. Can someone please help me?

```
sns.kdeplot(data=BM[:,-1])
```

[image]

Comment: Would be nice if you add solutions you've tried!

Comment: I have uploaded some of the methods i've used.

Comment: You should specify what ```sns```, ```plt``` and ```BM``` are. Althought some are obvious but not for all others who potentially could answer your question. If you're not going to post *mininum reproduceable example*, then you should clarify all names.

Comment: How does your BM[:,-1] look like? Which error do you get?

Comment: Hi Ale, it look like this :array([-0.00871515, -0.0001227 , -0.01449098, ...,  0.01808527, 0.00074193,  0.01145541]). The error is that the kde does not show up, it even changes the color of the histogram.

Comment: The scale of the y axis is a problem here. I suggest you normalize the histrogram or use `seaborn.distplot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `sns.kdeplot(BM['col1'])` where `'col1'` is the name of the column you want to plot.

I'll give you a reproducible example that works for me.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
BM = pd.DataFrame(np.array([-0.00871515, -0.0001227 , -0.01449098, 0.01808527, 0.00074193, 0.01145541]
                  , columns=['col1'])
BM.head(2)

    col1
0   -0.008715
1   -0.000123

sns.kdeplot(BM['col1'])
```

[image]

**Edit based on your additional question:**

To have the histogram and a kde plot use this one:

```
sns.distplot(BM['col1'])
```

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is how you access BM. Have you tried the way I did? np.random.rand is an numpy array. Try BM = pd.DataFrame(np.array([-0.00871515, -0.0001227 , -0.01449098, 0.01808527, 0.00074193, 0.01145541]), columns=['col1'])

Comment: Hi, i have tried what you did but still not working. I have retried my first method and its now working. However, i unable to plot them the KDE on the histogram.Refer to my first post(edited). Do you know how to do this?

Comment: How were you able to plot the KDE on the histogram, i've tried but it does not work. The kde and histogram goes separately.

Comment: I edited the answer to use exactly the same input you gave me.

Comment: Your're welcome: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok. Being a new user, i did not know that we should not say thank you

Comment: A thank you is always appreciated for me, but a thank you + accepted answer is even better :)

Comment: Unfortunately being a new user i do not have enough reputation to raise your point. Sorry. Ive accepted your answer however. I did not know i should do this earlier.